# Is there a maximum size for the registry's data item?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-registry

I'm trying to edit a registry entry on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server and on all entries when you right click on the name and select modify it allows you to edit the Data field.

One entry, however, has a lot of data and when I try to edit it the dialog shows no data. (In the list view and programatically I can pull the data from the field, however RegEdit does not appear to support the editing of this entry.)

Is there a maximum size for the registry's data item?

(I'm trying to get to the bottom of another problem that I have with this item and establishing the answer to this question is the first step.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Registry Element Size Limits**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
Registry Element    Size Limit

Key name            255 characters
Value name          16,383 characters

    Windows 2000:  260 ANSI characters or 16,383 Unicode characters.

Value           Available memory (latest format); 1 MB (standard format)

Tree    A registry tree can be 512 levels deep. You can create up to 32 levels at a time through a single registry API call.
```

Comment: Mr Askew - you are awesome!